# Return point feature from ImageWMS on click

Tags: geoserver, openlayers

I have a map with a point layer and I'm trying to create a popup on click which displays the properties of the points. My issue right now is that I can't get geoserver to return any features when I perform a getFeatureInfo() on my ImageWMS source.

This is the output:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":"unknown","features":[],"crs":null}
```

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Accessible Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.2.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/ol3-layerswitcher.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="layerswitcher.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/ol3-popup.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css" />
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="ol-debug.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a class="skiplink" href="#map">Go to map</a>
    <div id="map" class="map" tabindex="0">
        <script src="src/ol3-layerswitcher.js"></script>
        <script src="src/ol3-popup.js"></script>
    </div>
    <div id="info">&nbsp;</div>
    <button id="zoom-out">Zoom out</button>
    <button id="zoom-in">Zoom in</button>
    <script>
      var view = new ol.View({
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2
      });
      var lineLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
        title: 'Object Tail',
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url: 'http://localhost/geoserver/workspace/wms',
            params: {'LAYERS': 'workspace:table_lines'},
            maxZoom: 19
            }),
        visible: true,
        });
       var pointLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
        title: 'Object Points',
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url: 'http://localhost/geoserver/workspace/wms',
            params: {'LAYERS': 'workspace:table_points'},
            serverType: 'geoserver',
            maxZoom: 19
            }),
        visible: true,
        });
       var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
        title: 'Object Velocity',
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url: 'http://localhost/geoserver/workspace/wms',
            params: {'LAYERS': 'workspace:table_velocity'},
            maxZoom: 19
            }),
        visible: true,
        });
      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Group({
                'title': 'Base maps',
                layers: [
                    new ol.layer.Tile({
                        title: 'OSM',
                        type: 'base',
                        visible: true,
                        source: new ol.source.OSM()
                    })
                ]
            }),
              new ol.layer.Group({
                'title': 'Data layers',
                layers: [
                    lineLayer, vectorLayer, pointLayer
                ]
            })  
        ],
        target: 'map',
        controls: 
            ol.control.defaults({
          attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
            collapsible: false
          }), 
        }),
        view: view
      });

      var layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
        tipLabel: 'Legend' // Optional label for button
        });

    map.addControl(layerSwitcher);

    var popup = new ol.Overlay.Popup();
    map.addOverlay(popup);

    var displayFeatureInfo = function(coord, pixel)
    {
        var features;
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
        var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (view.getResolution());
        var url = pointLayer.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
            coord, viewResolution, 'EPSG:4326',
            {'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/json'});
        if (url) {
          features = url;
          document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
        }
        console.info('URL: ' + features);

    };

    map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
        displayFeatureInfo(evt.coordinate, evt.pixel);
    });


      document.getElementById('zoom-out').onclick = function() {
        var view = map.getView();
        var zoom = view.getZoom();
        view.setZoom(zoom - 1);
      };

      document.getElementById('zoom-in').onclick = function() {
        var view = map.getView();
        var zoom = view.getZoom();
        view.setZoom(zoom + 1);
      };

      var iFrequency = 5000;
      var myInterval = 0;

      myInterval = setInterval("updateLayers()", iFrequency);

      function updateLayers()
      {
        pointLayer.getSource().updateParams({"time": Date.now()});
        lineLayer.getSource().updateParams({"time": Date.now()});
        vectorLayer.getSource().updateParams({"time": Date.now()});
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on how to get it to return the point I'm clicking on?

EDIT: log

```
2017-07-19 08:09:23,902 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - Querying layer http://workspace.mysite.com:table_points with bbox: ReferencedEnvelope[3349019.462106293 : 3379594.273420363, -9729982.583352817 : -9699047.772038748]
2017-07-19 08:09:23,910 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CREATE CONNECTION
2017-07-19 08:09:23,916 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - SELECT "environment","identity","tracknumber",encode(ST_AsBinary("position"),'base64') as "position" FROM (select environment, identity, track_number as tracknumber, location as position from table
) as "vtable" WHERE   FALSE 
2017-07-19 08:09:23,925 DEBUG [org.geotools.jdbc] - CLOSE CONNECTION
2017-07-19 08:09:23,927 DEBUG [org.geotools.renderer.label] - TOTAL LINE LABELS : 0
2017-07-19 08:09:23,930 DEBUG [org.geotools.renderer.label] - PAINTED LINE LABELS : 0
2017-07-19 08:09:23,932 DEBUG [org.geotools.renderer.label] - REMAINING LINE LABELS : 0
2017-07-19 08:09:23,935 DEBUG [org.geotools.rendering] - Style cache hit ratio: NaN , hits 0, requests 0
2017-07-19 08:09:23,938 INFO [org.geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getFeatureInfo
    BaseUrl = http://localhost:80/geoserver/
    Exceptions = application/vnd.ogc.se_xml
    FeatureCount = 1
    Get = false
    GetMapRequest = 
GetMap Request
 version: 1.3.0
 output format: image/png
 width height: 101,101
 bbox: SRSEnvelope[3333120.5602229764 : 3394881.6790773985, -9745269.989009853 : -9683508.870155431]
 layers: workspace:table_points
 styles: cssPoint
    InfoFormat = application/json
    PropertyNames = null
    QueryLayers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@2da43adf]
    RawKvp = {CRS=EPSG:4326, FORMAT=image/png, INFO_FORMAT=application/json, I=50, STYLES=, J=50, WIDTH=101, TIME=1500473361257, HEIGHT=101, LAYERS=workspace:table_points, REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo, BBOX=3333120.5602229764,-9745269.989009853,3394881.6790773985,-9683508.870155431, VERSION=1.3.0, SERVICE=WMS, QUERY_LAYERS=workspace:table_points, TRANSPARENT=true}
    Request = GetFeatureInfo
    RequestCharset = null
    Version = 1.3.0
    XPixel = 50
    YPixel = 50
```

Comment: what does the geoserver log file say?

Comment: @iant Here are the logs, the only thing that stands out to me is the first line, where it references the table with the namespace URI instead of just workspace:table_points. The openlayers map is in my geoserver www directory, so do I need to change my workspace's namespace URI to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a projection issue.

Your request is specifying that the SRS is EPSG:4326 but your bounding box is definitely not in 4326, is it EPSG:3857?

If you insist on specifying the SRS for the getFeatureInfo request then you need to transform the bounding box to that projection, but I suspect that will break the rest of the request since the pixel of the click should change too.

Comment: Everything on my geoserver is in 4326. But I am using the ol.source.OSM() as my baselayer, which uses 3857. I'll see if I can force it to 4326.

Comment: I just added projection: 'EPSG:4326' to my view and it seems to be working now.